# recover folder permissions when access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2008, freenas, cifs

Ok.  So I apparently had a user go into the permissions settings of a folder on our network share and they proceeded to modify permissions without consulting me first.  Now the folder is inaccessible.  I am assuming that all the permissions that were on the folder, and its sub-folders, have been removed.

Is there any way for me to reestablish the previous permissions on a folder?  I have tried going to the parent folder to replicate the permissions back down, but that obviously doesn't work.

Quite honestly, I don't know a lot about folder permissions.  I know enough to block access for some users if needed, but don't know if there is a way for me to block user from changing permissions entirely.  That would be really helpful to know too.

As for the environment.  It is a Windows 2008 domain.  The folder is on a FreeNAS server CIFS share. There are only a few folders on the share that have had the permissions modified to restrict access.  If needed and if it is possible I could potentially fix this from the linux side then reset the needed permissions once access has been restored.

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be appreciated.  Even links to articles explaining this would be appreciated.  When I google, all I get back are results on how to set them if access isn't already being denied.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the root user on the linux side?

Comment: Yes.  It is FreeNAS and I have access to all portions of it.  I should also mention that FreeNAS is running in a VM on through VirtualBox on top of Ubuntu 12.04.  I haven't done it yet, but this will hopefully be changing to running in ESXi instead.

Comment: Can you give any details of what the user did? For instance, has he gone to the inaccessible sub-folder and made changes directly to it, or did he make changes to the parent folder which have been inherited by the child? You should probably ask him if he changed the owner of the folder - or if he just monkeyed with the access permissions without changing owner.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Permission changes were made on the actual folder.  The parent folder is still accessible (as well as everything else within the parent), however, permissions can not be replicated down to that particular child folder.  Is there an admin group within an Active Directory domain that is not affected by permissions; that has access to everything regardless of permissions that have been set?